# Automatically logout when user deletes Android Authenticator account from settings

Tags: android, authentication, android-authenticator

I have developed an app that uses the Android Authenticator API (*AccountManager*), so I can add or delete accounts via the settings screen.

If I log out from my application, I can programatically delete the account and return the user to the *AccountAuthenticatorActivity*. However, if the user deletes the account manually from the settings screen, I would like that my app (which is running) detected this condition and automatically logged out when re-opened.

I have thought in overwriting the *onResume* method in each activity (or extend from a new Activity class) and ask the Authenticator with *getAuthTokenByFeatures*, so when the app is resumed it would ask the user to login if the account was removed. Yet I'm new to Android and don't know if this is a good approach.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I have discovered the *addOnAccountsUpdatedListener* method in the [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) class.

Using that, I answer my own question. In the onCreate method of the main activity of my app:

```
    accountsListener = new OnAccountsUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAccountsUpdated(Account[] accounts) {
            Account[] myAccounts = mAccountManager.getAccountsByType(AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
            if (myAccounts.length == 0) {
                // The account has been deleted
                Intent i = new Intent(mContext, PromptLoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
            return;
        }
    };

    mAccountManager.addOnAccountsUpdatedListener(accountsListener, null, true);
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, you have to add this listener to every Activity of your app, since the user might be in any other activity of your app, not only in the main one.